# How to fire an event on hidden button inside div on click of div

Tags: jquery

Below is the code added to fire hidden button click event on div click. but when i click div, button click event is going into infinite loop. so please let me know how to solve this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#newDiv').click(function() {
    $("#button1").on("click", function() {
      console.log("in onclick");
    }).click();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newDiv"><button id="button1" hidden>Submit</button></div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question so it makes sense and is readable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The .get() method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object. If the value of `index` is out of bounds — less than the negative number of elements or equal to or greater than the number of elements — it returns `undefined`.

```js
$('#newDiv').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#btnHidden').get(-1).click();
});

$("#btnHidden").on("click", function() {
  console.log("Hidden Button Clicked");
});
```

```css
#newDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newDiv">
  <button id="btnHidden" hidden>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind your button click inside the div click otherwise you will bind a new event every time you click the div, bind it outside and just call the click in the div click:

```js
// bind this outside the div click event
$("#button1").on("click", function() {
  console.log("in onclick");
});

$('#newDiv').on("click", function() {
  $("#button1").get(0).click();       // I prefer to use click action on the native js object - seems to work better than the jquery click action
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newDiv">
  <button id="button1" hidden>Submit</button>
  click in div
</div>
```